# Kong Api Gateway Clustering

Tags: api, load-balancing, kong, kong-plugin, konga

I have some questions according to https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/clustering

I’ll really appreciated if someone help me.

1)according to Clustering Reference I need a load balancer , could you please introduce me a free one which I  can use in front of my Kong nodes?

2)I still don’t know is it better to implement kong nodes in different VMs or in Docker using docker-compose file for a fully production environment ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think both your questions are highly dependent of your tech stack / architecture.

Regarding the load balancing question, I can think of several options for different  options:

- DNS Load Balancing, which depends on client side load balancing
- Services in an Kubernetes/OpenShift environment, which provide load balancing across a bunch of pods
- AWS Load Balancers, if you deploy Kong directly on EC2 machines. (I am sure other cloud providers have simar concepts)

Whether you deploy Kong on a VM or as a Docker Container is quite hard to answer. It depends on your tech stack you already have in place and on your requirements (see https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/sizing-guidelines/). However, I would not recommend to use docker-compose for this use case. If you decide for a Docker-based solution you should take a look at container management solutions such as Kubernetes or OpenShift. There you have solved the management of your Kong containers (such as how many replicas are running and what happens if one replica is failing) and you have solved the load balancing issue (by using Kubernetes/OpenShift services objects).